# Double slit experiment from first principles of QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

I have read many descriptions of electron double slit experiment but I could not find the description from the first principles of quantum mechanics. Most of the descriptions makes comparison with light waves or water waves and after some arguments from optics explain why the interference happens. Light waves and water wave description are not fundamental, they are phenomenological models. Could somebody explain the electron double slit interference only from the first principles of quantum mechanics? I know the answer from the Feynman path integral approach but I would like to understand it from the pre-Feynman Integral approach.

Comment: Please make sure that I have read all the answers related to this question in the PSE. I am looking for a rigorous description of electron double slit interference patters only from the first principles of quantum mechanics (but not the Feynman Integral approach)

Comment: If you accept Schrodinger equation, you just have to consider  infinite potential in the plan $z=0$ of the slits (except for the $2$ slits where the potential is zero); of course, you have to do numerical simulations.

Comment: Thank you for your insight but I have difficulty with performing the numerical simulations. It that the only way to explain it ? I am basically interested to understand why the two probability amplitudes due to the two slits are what they are? Basically the prepared states are definite momentum states along a direction perpendicular to the plane of the slits and the screen. What causes the probability amplitude to be identical with the prepared states?

Comment: " What causes the probability amplitude to be identical with the prepared states?" You must mean something else, as the amplitude is a number, not a state. Also, what about Feynman path integral disturbs you? It is from first principles, is it not? Just as some problems are hideously complicated in Newtonian mechanics but crystal clear in Lagrangian mechanics, so it can occur in QM that the path integral solves elegantly what is otherwise very ugly.

Comment: Dear ACuriousMind, What I am interested to know is how to establish the probability amplitude of the expressions in the Copenhagen interpretation. The probability amplitude from the two slits are only different in phase but have the same wave number. I could not understand how does that happen? I am asking this question to understand the Copenhagen interpretation in relation to the double slit experiment.

Comment: You have to add @ before my name, else I don't get notified to your reply. I'm not sure I fully understand you, but are you asking why the interpretation of scalar products, known as the [Born rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule), holds? Then the answer is: Within the standard Copenhagen framework, it is an axiom, and alternative frameworks might have it as a derivation, but then they will have some other axioms instead.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, It makes sense to me what you are trying to say. Could you please elaborate it, with connection to Born rule, as a complete answer? It would be good for others as well.

Comment: @Sbaniala : For the most simple approach, the mathematics are quite the same as the [Classical wave-optics formulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Classical_wave-optics_formulation). However, the Quantum interpretation is that these are probability amplitudes, and not real light wavefunctions. You sum the probability amplitudes with the correct phase difference, and then you take the square of the modulus to have the probability.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think a complete treatment exists. There is a paper by Marcella which gives some arguments. https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0703126

However it is not a really solid argument (see criticism at https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.2408)

Comment: Link-only answers are not usually well-received around here. You might want to expand this answer to include the arguments of the papers.

Comment: It's also best to link to the arXiv abstract pages so users on mobile devices can choose whether to download the pdfs. Welcome to the site, by the way.